# sitemap in google search console showing "see index coverage" link disabled

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, search-engines, technical-seo

In Google Search Console I observed that "See Index Coverage" is disabled.

also it is not indexing 2 post from last 20-30 days

what i have tried is

delete existing sitemap and added new with same name.

[image: Check this image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to be positioned with Google WebMaster Tools. Some information needs several days to be shown the first time and also updates take quite long.

Additionally, you cannot force Google to Index pages faster from a sitemap, but if you want one or two pages to be indexed (or crawled at least) there is a menu for this. You can give GWT a hint to look at a particular URL.

When you have the first results, take time with analysis.